# Is there any config options in Grunt stylus for --disable-cache flag in stylus?

Tags: gruntjs, stylus

Can grunt-contrib-stylus compile stylus files like `stylus --disable-cache dir/`?

Are there any config options in grunt-contrib-stylus which can achieve the `--disable-cache` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
options: { cache: false }
```

Comment: I'm sure it's an answer (I tried it and it works) :)